# Coding JSF, commandButton's navigation-action-outcome by Code

Tags: jsf, facelets, ajax4jsf

i try to fix unmanagable code like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="dia_ok" actionListener="#{...}" ajaxSingle="true" .../>
```

i fix it by bind the button to an ManagedBean and swap all the attributes to Java-Code, so ill only have:

```
<a4j:commandButton binding="#{...}"/>
```

I successfully coded setAjaxSingle(true) and the actionListener-attribute, but i fail on code the action-Attribute.

My question is: how can i specify the action-outcome whereat the method button.setActionExpression() does only allows argument of MethodExpression instead of String?

Comment: Why do you consider your fix an improvement? (The most frequent advice I hear about component bindings is to avoid them at all costs ...)

Comment: Isn't one goal of agile programming a code-dietary by architecture-review? The commandButton uses 8-12 more attributes, its imo unmanageamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a `MethodExpression` with a value of `"dia_ok"` and a return type of `String`. The expression does not necessarily refer to `"#{bean.action}"` or something.

E.g.

```
button.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("dia_ok", String.class));
```

with

```
private static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        facesContext.getELContext(), expression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}
```

I only fail to see how it makes the code more manageable as you're mingling the view into the model this way. Perhaps you need to writeup some general convention how attributes should be ordered/organized so that it's better manageable? E.g. `id` first, then `value`, etc and then be consistent with this convention.

Comment: I don't use the mvc-pattern, i wrote an generic CRUD-curator-class and my hibernate-entitybeans (transactional long-lifed hibernatesession) inherits the jsf-selectitem. Its an tricky prototype and throws all important classic oop-design away.